# Removing Objects from JSON using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a `test.json` file which has the below structure:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "class": "4",
  "exam": "test",
  "marks": "4"
}
```

I want to remove some pairs from it like exam and class, and ultimately it should look like below:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "marks": "4"
}
```

How can I do it from PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your post was not completely clear if you wanted to remove certain keys, or if you only wanted to retain `marks` and `name`. The code below performs the latter:

```
Get-Content 'test.json' -Raw | 
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    Select-Object name, marks | 
    ConvertTo-Json
```

Result:

```json
{
    "name":  "test",
    "marks":  "4"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

powershell cmd:

```
$obj = Get-Content .\aaa.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj.psobject.properties.remove('exam')
$obj.psobject.properties.remove('class')
$obj | ConvertTo-Json
```

output:

```
{
    "name":  "test",
    "marks":  "4"
}
```